# Is the HTML preview custom built or available online?

Tags: discussion

I want something similiar to Stackoverflow's 'as you type' preview of the post you're writing. Was it custom built or is it a freely available as jQuery/mootools etc add on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was (de-obfuscated/reverse-engineered) by the SO team. See https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/wmd-editor-reverse-engineered/

Comment: It's part of WMD - no reverse engineering was necessary

Comment: The blog-title "WMD Editor Reverse Engineered" is confusing then :)

Comment: More correctly, it's a pared-down version of WMD.

Comment: Well, they had to 'reverse-engineer' the obfuscated and minimized WMD code.